# How to change standard sharepoint Calender to work with it in other culture?

Tags: 2010, calendar, language

my problem is that how to create custom calender in share point to use it.

I want to replace standard sharepoint calender with persian calender to work with it in all sharepoint parts.

any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution on a following issue to change the default language to alternate language programmatically using which the sharepoint designer's actions and conditions language doesn't change below is the javascript code:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('ChangeLanguage');

function ChangeLanguage()

{

//script fetches current display language

var lcid =_spPageContextInfo.currentLanguage;

//1033 language code for Persian

if(lcid.toString()!=1025)

{

var today = new Date();

var oneYear = new Date(today.getTime() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

var url = window.location.href;

//script changes current display language to arabic i.e 1025

document.cookie = "lcid=" + 1025 + ";path=/;expires=" + oneYear.toGMTString();

window.location.href = url;

}

}
```